# Symfony 1.4: How to limit results of the index action to only those of the logged in user

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, dql

I apologize in advance for this newb question, but I've been struggling with the proper way to go about getting the correct result.

I have two tables:

```
sf_guard_user:
  Columns
    id
    name

recipe:
  Columns:
    id:
    user_id:
    name:
  relations:
    sf-guard_user: { local: user_id, foreign: id; foreign_alias: recipes }
```

Recipe module, indexSuccess:
This form is where I want to limit my results to only the logged in user.

Here is my recipe actions.class.php file:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
$this->recipe = Doctrine_Core::getTable('recipe')
  ->createQuery('a')
  ->whereStatement: user_id = logged-in/posted user (this is where I'm struggling with the syntax... do I use a join statement? Or where statement?  ...I'm lost.  I can get the result I want in basic MySql, but not in DQL)
  ->execute();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it, not to edit the question. In this way, it will be easier for other readers to understand the question and the answer.

Comment: I tried that... the forum wouldn't let me b/c it hadn't been 8 hours.  I'll re-post in an answer format.  Thanks for the suggestion and the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of both respondents I was able to get it working with an additional method in the myUser.class.php file.  Here's how I got it working:

In the following file: project>>apps>>frontend>>lib>>myUser.class.php

I added this method:

```
public function getId()
{
  return $this->getGuardUser()->getId();
}
```

And in the following file: project>>apps>>frontend>>modules>>recipe>>actions>>actions.class.php

I revised the executeIndex action to:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->recipes = RecipeTable::getInstance()->findByUserId($this->getUser()->getId());
}
```

Thanks again to both respondents.

Answer (score 3):

a shorter way would be:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->recipes = RecipeTable::getInstance()->findByUserId($this->getUser()->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`->where('user_id = ?', $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId(););`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Darhazer, however, that didn't quite work.  I get this error:

Call to undefined method myUser::getUserId

It probably would have been helpful to mention that I am using the sfDoctrinGuardPlugin.

Comment: My bad, the method is getId()